# How to convert a minimization problem to maximization problem and vice versa

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

So i have this LP problem

[image]

that can be transformed into

[image]

Now thanks to previous users I know that to transform min to max all i need to to is multiply the objective function by -1

But say i want to transform a maximization function to a minimization function?

1) is there any use in doing so ?

2) if there is any use, what would the relationship be?

Please explain in the simplest way possible; i am new to this topic. Thanks!

Comment: You have $\min \ z=-x_1$. Now you want to apply the simplex algorithm. This algorithm is basically for maximization problems. To apply this algorithm for minimization problems you maximize $-z=x_1$.

Comment: Any reply, Sara?

Comment: Thanks! So this works only when transforming min to max. If i have a max function i will just leave it as it is for simplicity?

Comment: May you help me on my other question too that i just posted ? Its about finding optimal values of this same optimization problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At the other question I would use the simplex algorithm as well.

Comment: How would i use it? Because im not sure im my answer on the other question is right or the answer sheet answer is right. Mind helping on the other question ?

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you showed me if the answer sheet was right or wrong... this is confusing me so much !! You would be a savor

Comment: Are you familiar with the simplex algorithm?

Comment: Not quite... but in the question i thought that x2=1 and then i would apply that to the first constraint. because if i use the same answers as the answers sheet then on the  second constraint x2 is not equal to 1 but to 0. I never studied the simplex algorithm and i wish to answer the question in one of the two methods i showed...

Comment: You´re thinking in the right direction. I don´t know if I´m able to verify it now since it is very hot here in Germany.

Comment: Why didn't the constraints too be converted? By the way isn't converting a min-to-max or max-to-min LPs the same as converting an LP to standard form?